# A problem about symmetric and skew-symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

A is symmetric(skew-symmetric) matrix and B is nonsingular matrix . 
What can i say about this $$BAB^T$$
???

Answer (score 3):

Note that

$(BAB^T)^T = B^{TT}A^TB^T = BA^TB^T, \tag 1$

since

$B^{TT} = B. \tag 2$

If $A$ is symmetric, $A = A^T$, so

$(BAB^T)^T = BAB^T, \tag 3$

that is, $BAB^T$ is symmetric.  Likewise if $A$ is skew-symmetric, $A^T =-A$, so

$(BAB^T)^T = B(-A)B^T= -BAB^T; \tag 4$

$BAB^T$ is skew-symmetric in this case.  $BAB^T$ inherits the symmetry or skew-symmetry of $A$.  The non-singularity of $B$ plays no role in these conclusions; they hold whether $B$ is singular or not.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the transpose of a product is the product of transposes in reverse order.

Comment: , Can you explain more ?